# MS Teams tab app not getting loading

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am new to MS teams development, I was following [MS Teams Tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/build-your-first-app/build-and-run), but when I do `npm start` it only shows [image: this screen].

Also, when I try to debug using **F5** in my VSCode, the app does not run, instead, it opens the **Apps** section of Teams... Please suggest

Comment: You need to check  in teams you will find your app in there add it as personal tab in one of the channels

Comment: Checked, not found any app